# how to make my 3 column CSS Footer responsive

Tags: css

I'm using these media queries in CSS to make my footer responsive.

I want to make the 3 columns (`#footer-left`, `#footer-middle`, `#footer-right`) automatically move under each other when the screen is made smaller.

what would be the best way of doing this? I have a fiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5tuC/)

```
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #footer-left {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }
    #footer-middle {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        border-right:none;
    }
    #footer-right {
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }
    #footer-bottom {
        display:none;
    }
}

/* for 800px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    #footer-left {
        border-right:none;
    }
    #footer-middle {
        margin-left: 0px;
        border-right:none;
    }
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #footer-left {
        border-right:none;
    }
    #footer-middle {
        margin-left: 0px;
        border-right:none;
    }           
}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #footer-right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `#footer-left`, `#footer-middle`, and `#footer-right` divs all be `width:100%` when you want them to stack, with `float:none` on each of them. Your width may need to be less than 100% if you keep padding on any of the divs (in your case, width would be 92%, since you've got it set up for 4% padding on left and right of each div).